# Z-index issue on iOS Safari & Chrome

Tags: ios, css, html

I'm having an issue with a responsive dropdown menu, based on wordpress Underscores theme.

It looks okay on desktop but not on iOS Safari including iPad and iPhone.

[image]

I've tried to add z-index to other divs as well but it doesn't work. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Post a url and I can look in developer tools.

Comment: z-index only works on elements that are non-statically positioned, i.e. relative, absolute or fixed

Answer (score 29):

There is actually a fourth method, with translate3d:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
```

iOS browsers fully support CSS3, so you can use this safely.

Comment: Oddly I was able to fix an iOS-specific z-index issue thanks to this answer (I went with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);`). Does anyone know why this works? Apple's [own docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/Using2Dand3DTransforms/Using2Dand3DTransforms.html) say, "An element’s z-index has nothing to do with its z-axis coordinate", yet this trick only works when the z-axis is modified…if left "translated" 0px it doesn't work! So it's different than the usual "transforms introduce stacking contexts" behavior…

Comment: This method helped me a lot in other situations as well, the most recent being fixing a semi-transparent element in a flipping panel (Chrome issue only): the semi-transparent element kept reappearing when showing the back face of the flipping panel but by applying this code to the element I managed to fix the issue.

Comment: This actually worked for me when I applied it on the correct parent element that was experiencing the z-index issue. I had an issue where a checkbox was showing from underneath a dropdown menu. This was only happening on ios web mobile (safari/chrome)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways you can handle this:
    1. You can set the z-index value to a large number like 80 or 90.
    2. You can add the menu element after the other divs (so by default it will place on other items)
    3. You can set the z-index of the text in the divs to be less than that of the menu div.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just apply a z-index to your dropdown menu - what you need to do is apply z-indicies to sibling elements to ensure the correct stacking order.

Without seeing your HTML, it's not possible to determine where they should go. But the best I can say is apply a z-index to your entire nav bar and one to your entire content div. Keep in mind that, as Ajay said, in order for z-indicies to work correctly the elements they are applied to have to be positioned non-statically (in your case position: relative would most likely be the best option).

Answer (score 0):

If dropdown menu's parent element is nav, you should put z-index a large number to it, higher than other element