# Z-index issue on IOS browsers but not on android browsers

Tags: html, ios, css

The dropdown menu mixes up with the existing view when the menu button is clicked. It was supposed to be over the existing view, without mixing up. I referred to this solution too but to no avail:
[Z-index issue on iOS Safari & Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255511/z-index-issue-on-ios-safari-chrome)

This is the css for navigation:

```
#nav .nav.navbar-nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

This is working perfect on desktop browsers and android browsers but not on iphone browsers.
I also tried to increment `z-index` and also `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,999px);`, but nothing is working good.
Any solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What solution did you end up with here?